# Cannot create react app template. npm hangs

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create react app template on windows 10 by using command:

`npx create-react-app app`

however npx hangs and does not output anything on the screen.

I also tried to install the package create-react-app by running

`npm i -g create-react-app`

it hanged as well, so after googling I stumbled upon answer to change npm setting:

`npm config set prefix pathToPrefix`

and I was able to install this package into provided folder, but npx still did not work. I also tried to install this package locally, not globally and npm was still hanging, but when I`ve run:

`npm install create-react-app --verbose`

it worked and I was able to install the package. I wanted to follow guides how to install create-react-app without using npx for example by running:

`npm run create-react-app app` but it does not work and whatever I try it tells me that package.json cannot be found. I looked into the package directory and there was no package.json anywhere so it's obvious it will not work.

I have the newest node and npm version, I made fresh install as well. I have run `npm cache clean --force` several times. I am using git console. I also tried that in Powershell console but running this command shrinked powershell window. I was running the consoles both as user and admin.

Is there any other way I could use this package to create app template? Do you have any ideas why `npx` hangs?

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem specific to `create-react-app`, but instead to npm in general. Are you able to install other packages globally? You may want to edit your question to be more generalized. Have you tried this (workaround to issue with global npm/npx): `mkdir test && cd test && npm init -y && npm i create-react-app && npx create-react-app app`? I would also check that you don't have two versions of npm? Try `which npm` to see where the npm you're using is located.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried many other method and still failed, try this instead :

- go to your window 10 search bar, type `Resource Monitor`, press enter
- Click the `CPU` tab
- Now, whenever it freezes/hang, just search for `cmd.exe`, right click, and choose `Resume Process`

[image: This is what you should do]

- Now just repeat the above step every time it freeze until complete.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Try create-react-app in a different folder**, totally outside of `C:\Users`.

That means, **DO NOT USE** `Desktop`, `Documents`, `OneDrive`, `Downloads`, etc.

---

It seems that in some *Windows 10* environment, there's additional protection mechanism against random script from messing with user data. In this case create-react-app probably doesn't check error code from system commands and fails to properly show the errors.

For example my `mkdir` fails in `Documents` folder:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Documents> mkdir tmp
mkdir : Could not find file 'tmp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mkdir tmp
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\tmp:String) [New-Item], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

PS C:\Users\xxx\Documents>
```

But works elsewhere:

```
PS Z:\> cd c:\
PS C:\> mkdir tmp1


    Directory: C:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         1/10/2021   2:50 PM                tmp1


PS C:\>
```