# create-react-app stops and does not create a new app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

when I try to run `npx create-react-app myapp` it stalls after sometime no error is given, it just doesen't do anything, it still looks like it's it's trying to install but nothing happens, I have installed node 16.14.2 on windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738299/cannot-create-react-app-template-npm-hangs?rq=1 does this answer your question.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad yes but also using powershell instead of cmd

Comment: hm I'm still having problems with it @DurgaPrasad